# ubuntu/nginx reverse proxy for ORDS with Oauth in SSL

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy

I need to setup a reverse-proxy taking incoming requests and redirecting them to another host, which is a ORDS service.
I need to use `ubuntu/nginx` image on a k8s pod, but I don't know nginx, and i'm still quite ignorant when it comes to the subject of ssl and certificates, and all I read looks jibberish...

In summary:

- I have an ORDS at `https://my.ords.com:1234`
- I will have a reverse proxy in nginx at domain `https://my.domain.com/`
- `https://my.domain.com/ords/*` calls will be transformed by the proxy as `https://my.ords.com:1234/ords/*` calls

  - `[POST] https://my.domain.com/ords/auth/token` should become `https://my.ords.com:1234/ords/auth/token` (this is the OAuth2.0 part)
  - `[*] https://my.domain.com/ords/user/module/*` should become `[*] https://my.ords.com:1234/ords/user/module/*`.

I've been starting with this snippet, but all the tls/ssl part is the one i'm missing...

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events { }

http {
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        listen 443 default_server;
        listen [::]:443 default_server;

        server_name my.domain.com;

        location /ords/ {
            proxy_pass https://my.ords.com:1234/;
            proxy_buffering off;
            # have Nginx relay the real caller IP address
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        }
    }
}
```

and i launch the container with the command provided in docker-hub:

```
docker run -d --name ngnx -e TZ=UTC -p 443:443 -v .\nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf ubuntu/nginx
```

I've been looking at all kind of docs, and still having problem understanding the thematic...

- https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-subrequest-authentication/#complete-example
- https://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#proxy
  https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass
  https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location
- https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/How-to-setup-Nginx-reverse-proxy-servers-by-example
- https://pentacent.medium.com/nginx-and-lets-encrypt-with-docker-in-less-than-5-minutes-b4b8a60d3a71
- [Dockerized NGINX Reverse Proxy SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60342528/dockerized-nginx-reverse-proxy-ssl)
- [Nginx proxy for OAuth2 validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44300569/nginx-proxy-for-oauth2-validation)
- (. . .)

Could anybody help me understand all this stuff and put pieces together?